# Why we use Static Members on C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Can someone explain what is main difference between Instance and Static Members with real examples?

Comment: I suggest a good book and/or online tutorial (plenty available via google).

Comment: Look up "singleton" which can be an example of using static

Comment: static members belong to the class. instance members belong to the instance. (and there are alot more useful instances of static members than just singletons)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't create **instances** for static classes. You just call them using their type name.

For example.

```
public static StaticClass {
   public static void StaticMethod(){}
}
```

To call the static method, you will just type this, `StaticClass.StaticMethod()`.

When you create an object of a class, it is known as creating an instance of that class. You can only create **instance** of **concrete** classes).

For example

```
public class ConcreteClass {

public void RandomMethod(){}

}
```

To call `RandomMethod`, you will have to create an **instance** of the `ConcreteClass` by creating an object.

```
ConcreteClass abc = new ConcreteClass();
abc.RandomMethod();
```

Also note that, in a static class, all it's members will have to be static and this makes sense because, since you will not be instantiating the class, you should be able to call it's members directly. This is why in my static class example above, the method too is also static.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The question never once mentions static classes.

Answer (score 0):

Static Members are run without using the implied "this" parameter which is the instance reference to the object that Instance Method was called from.

```
var number = Int32.TryParse("1234"); // Static member of Int32.  
//Is not called using an object, it doesnt not need the 'this' 
//because it doesn't change the data of the class.

string stringy = "asdfasdf";

char [] characters = stringy.ToCharArray();
//requires the strings data so it needs the instance stringy.
```

If the classes data is needed then you need an instance. If not you can make the method static so that it can be called at any time without an object.

Edit: I Initially read that as static methods. Static Data Members are completely different. When your program runs there is exactly one data object of that type allocated and is accessible via the class name not an instance of the class.

```
public class Classy
{
    public static int number= 4;

    public static void func() { }

    // Other non-static fields and properties...
}

//mainline..
//
int n = Classy.number;
Classy.func(); // etc..
```